# Once citation in combination with bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I use Bibtex for my bibliography, but I am concerned about the file growing to large to be maintainable. In particular, a considerable amount of my citations occur only once in a project, and I do not want to place in the Bib-tex file just because of just a few lines that put sugar to my thesis.

Can I combine Bibtex with "once-citation", such that the following might be possible:

```
A few more funny jokes can be found in
\citeonce{EHG50}{type="article", author="Einstein, Grothendieck, Hilbert", title="Really good jokes!" },
which we higly recommend for further references to the topic.
```

such that the citation is placed in the bibliography. If something similar is achievable, I'll appreciate it as well.

Comment: Nobody knows your `bibliographystyle` or which packages are loaded. Please add a minimal working example.

Comment: It's not common practice on TeX.sx to downvote questions that are generally okay but would benefit from additional information (that's what comments are there for). Downvotes have generally been reserved to mark questions that are considered unsalvageable, rude or spam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need a unique big bibliography database: you can use, for example,

```
\bibliography{main,sec1,sec2}
```

where you have bibliography databases `main.bib`, `sec1.bib` and `sec2.bib`. Write a `once.bib` file in the same directory as the document you're preparing with

```
@misc{EHG50,
  author={Einstein, A. and Grothendieck, A. and Hilbert, D.},
  title={Really good jokes},
}
```

in it, and call

```
\bibliography{main,once}
```

where, again, `main.bib` is your big bibliography database.

BibTeX can only read `.aux` file for collecting citation keys and `.bib` file for resolving them.

It's conceivable to define `\citeonce` in such a way that it writes out a `.bib` file with the provided data and to patch `\bibliography` so that it makes BibTeX look also at the created file, but it seems a too complicated approach.